# How to install SonataAdminBundle on Wamp?

Tags: php, symfony, github, cmd, symfony-sonata

I am try to install Sonata Admin Bundle on WAMP . To begin, add the dependent bundles to the **vendor/bundles** directory. Add the following lines to the file **deps**.

```
[SonatajQueryBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonatajQueryBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/jQueryBundle

[SonataUserBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/UserBundle

[SonataAdminBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/AdminBundle

[KnpMenuBundle]
    git=https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Knp/Bundle/MenuBundle

[KnpMenu]
    git=https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu.git
    target=/knp/menu

[SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/DoctrineORMAdminBundle
```

Now problem in install these bundle in vendor. I run this commend  `php bin/vendors install` but it's show `Try to run ./bin/vendors install --reinstall`

Is there something wrong with my Bundle. I am really not sure what to do about this. Please help.

I appreciate all the help.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to run suggested command? php bin/vendors install --reinstall?

Comment: Yes i am also run this  ./bin/vendors install --reinstall but it's still same problem!

Comment: Completely delete whole /vendor directory and run bin/vendors install

Answer (score 0):

You might be using incompatible versions of `Symfony` and `SonataAdminBundle`.

Also, you might be missing `SonataBlockBundle` and `SonataCacheBundle` which are required with the latest versions of `SonataAdminBundle` (have a look at the [SonataAdmin installation reference](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-0/doc/reference/installation.html)). `Symfony`, `SonataAdminBundle` and `Doctrine2` only work together in specific combinations.

**Suggestion:** Try the relevant instructions in [this tutorial](http://www.itsalif.info/content/symfony2-sonata-admin-bundle-boilerplate-install), or better yet, clone [this repository](https://github.com/liquidlabs/Symfony2-Sonata-Admin-Boilerplate) and configure it according to the instructions.

You'll have a working install, to which you can then add your existing bundle.